# draw an image in node.js

Tags: image, node.js, drawing

I'd like to create an application using node.js which creates an image. In the image I'd like to programmatically draw circles, lines or any function f(x) (well I could draw that function by adding points at some coordinates). I'd like to know which node.js modules I should use, or if there is something created for this.

In other words I need to draw a given mathematical functions and export it to an image file.

Thanks.

Comment: At a basic level, you'll need something like ImageMagick.  Sounds to me though that you might want a higher level library on top of that for plotting.

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas) which is a canvas implementation for Node.js

Source code example:

```
var Canvas = require('canvas')
  , canvas = new Canvas(200,200)
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '30px Impact';
ctx.rotate(.1);
ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);

var te = ctx.measureText('Awesome!');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(50, 102);
ctx.lineTo(50 + te.width, 102);
ctx.stroke();

console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
```